# Select and echo a random entry from an XML file in php

Tags: php, xml

I am new to XML, please help. I have a small xml file like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VISITOR> 
    <VID="1">
        <NAME>Irena Lyns</NAME>
        <FROM>Shenfield</FROM>
        <COMMENT>I'm so glad I came.Everything is so beautiful.</COMMENT>
    </VID> 
    <VID="2">
        <NAME>Gabriella</NAME>
        <FROM>ITALIA</FROM>
        <COMMENT>Wonderful!!! </COMMENT>
    </VID>
</VISITOR>
```

What is the code I would need to display a random VID, NAME, FROM and COMMENT on my php page?

Thank you in advance!!! :)

Comment: This is not valid XML. You cannot have element names `<VID="1">` and `<VID="2">`

Comment: Thanks I noticed this after, there was supposed to be a space after the V . Thanks for pointing it out though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parse it with [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) and chose random record from result - look at examples